# How to correct "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" in MSaccess?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, ms-access-2007

When i am running the following code in jre 7 is working fine.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con_db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:/runtime/handling.mdb; Readonly=False;");
```

When i run the same code in JDK i am getting the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

I am using the jackcess-1.1.18.jar for both the cases.

Now i my requirement is to run the code in JDK 1.7 . let anyone help me in solving the issue

This cases is for the eclipse of Helio version . But when i am running the same code in the luna version i am getting error for the both the cases.

Comment: It might be a 64 bit/32 bit problem. Do you use 32 bit or 64 bit Java, and do you have the 32 bit or 64 bit Access ODBC driver installed? The bitness of both should match.

Comment: I am using the 64 bit java . I think i am using the 64 Access driver too. Thing is Helios with Jre its working fine but not in the luna version.